# After I eat some foods beer tastes weird?

Tags: beer, flavor

I'm an obsessive home brewer.  So I'm always trying to critically evaluate the flavour of beers I make with a view to constantly improving their quality. In particular I am searching for off-flavours, like by-products of fermentation, or is *some-ingredient* too prominent in the flavour profile.

However I find that if I eat certain foods (like flavoured chips/crisps), before drinking beer, some parts of the malt taste profile (or the yeast?) flavours go weird, the sweetness becoming kind of saccharine (maybe).

Some foods do not prompt this at all, e.g.: unflavoured corn chips/crisps, salted peanuts.

Is this a know phenomenon? 
Is there a way to "reset" one's palette?

But this is really a question about food & flavours.  I'd like to prepare meals (and snacks) that don't make beer taste weird.

(Note: cross-posted to "Seasoned Advice")

Comment: Eating a piece of bread before you taste beer does wonders.

Answer (score 4):

Certain foods can have effects on taste buds. Rinsing your mouth out with water (not mouthwash as that can do the same thing) will help. This is why we learn to food and beer (or wine) parings.

When I do bottle shares, always have water available, or bland foods to rinse a certain beer out, and that way one taste does not have an effect on the next.

Comment: I've seen some beer judges eating bread or smelling vegetal charcoal to sort of reset the palate between samples.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the must read for you: [https://www.amazon.com/Tasting-Beer-Insiders-Worlds-Greatest/dp/1603420894](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1603420894)

More to that, BJCP judging guidelines recommend judges to abstain from eating too spicy or hot food even on the night before the judging. No coffee in the morning, and only water with plain crackers are allowed on tables while judging.